# How to get download link from a order in Woo-commerce?

Tags: php, woocommerce

I am trying to get download link of a product in Order data. But i am getting error.

Below is my code:

```
$order = new WC_Order( 206956 );

foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {

    echo $product_id = $item->get_product_id(); // product ID

    $downloads = $item->get_item_downloads();
    print_r ( $downloads );

}
```

I tried this solution also.

```
$order->get_item_downloads();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code:

```
$order = new WC_Order( 206956 );

if( $order->has_downloadable_item() && $order->is_paid() && $order->is_download_permitted() ){
    // Loop through order items with downloadable items
    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ){
        $product_id = $item->get_product_id(); // product ID

        // Get the downloadbles files (array):
        $downloads = $item->get_item_downloads();
        if( ! empty( $downloads ) ) {
            // Loop through downloads
            foreach( $downloads as $download_id => $download ) {
                // Output formatted download name and link
                echo '<p>' . $download['name'] . ' <a href="' . $download['download_url'] . '">' . __("Download link") . '</a></p>';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know if you find any issues.

Comment: No data coming in while loop.

Comment: This works when order status is completed.